# How can I pass a variable number of arguments in a Func type declaration?

Tags: vb.net, func, delegation

I have to implement a control in VB.Net where one of the properties is a function: basically, the user will set a certain function as an argument during the creation of the control, and the control will do something accordingly. A short example:

```
' Signature of the property
Public Property VarMethod As Func(Of DataRow, String)    

' Assigning the function to the control
control.VarMethod = AddressOf ToBeCalled

' Function that should be called
Private Function ToBeCalled(row as DataRow) As String
```

Something like that. I'd like to alter the property so that it can accept functions with a variable number of arguments, in case the row isn't enough for the function: basically, it should work even with functions like, for example, ToBeCalled(row as Datarow, index as Integer). I thought I could do something with ParamArray, but Func doesn't seem to accept it in the definition: adding a Object() to the definition, on the other hand, forces me to insert the secondary parameters every time. Do you know if there's a way to define the type Func so that it works the way I want it to? Thanks

Comment: You have answered your qeustion already. It is not possible to have a dynamic number of strongly typed parameters in a Func, Action, Delegate or Lambda. You can go with the `object()` array approach and use a default value of your index, e.g. -1, and have logic in `ToBeCalled` to ignore the index if it is -1.

Comment: So it's impossible... I'll try to find another solution then, thank you!

Comment: Maybe it´s feasible that you have several Properties on your control, each for a specific function syntax.